# How does linux recognize what input driver it needs to load?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've been studying input GNU/Linux drivers, for example [usb mouse driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbmouse.c), I think I get how they interact with , but I don't understand how kernel recognizes a type of device to load this driver for it. I've looked through [Linux Device Drivers](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) diagonally, but haven't found anything about this matter.

Any advice about what should I read to understand this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background: kernel sends what is called uevents using [kobject_uevent_env](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/kobject_uevent.c#L164) function. This uevents are read by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) daemon from netlink socket (earlier versions used hotplug). Before start, udev preloads rules from `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, this rules contain information about what need to be done as reaction to appropriate uevent from kernel (f.e. insmod a module).

Now about what you have asked. Typically what is shipped with uevent message is a MODALIAS, it could look like this:

```
MODALIAS = usb:v046DpC03Ed2000dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02
```

The USB device stores vendor id and device id, they are used, also, when MODALIAS is constructed. The kernel device drivers, which could be loaded dynamically (.ko files) also store the device identificators, this driver could work with. The driver could announce that it works with appropriate device/vendor id using [MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h#L212) macro. So that is how the relationship between device and dynamic module is established.

Comment: "*So that is how the relationship between device and dynamic module is established."* -- This summation statement is far too broad; you have only described USB devices.  The OP's title is not restricted to just USB devices.  I.E. devices, such as ADCs, UARTs, even the USB controllers, on another peripheral bus as found in the typical SoC, are rarely self-identifying.

Comment: @sawdust If you don't like the answer, you could propose your own. I will be glad if you could explain the things you have mentioned. I posted just a piece of information what I'am aware about.

Comment: AlexHoppus, unfortunately I would agree with @sawdust. You answer describes a particular case. If OP is okay with it, that is then.